# PVC card sublimation transfer

Tags: print-design, print-production

Can you do sublimation transfer on a normal PVC card or does it have to be a "thermal" PVC card (used in Evolis or Fargo printer)?

What is special with these thermal PVC cards? Do they have special layer that purports sublimation transfer?

Thanks,
v

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Hardware questions are generally off-topic here. You should check in your printers' user manual, or contact the printer manufacturer to find out which stock you can use with your printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublimation printing typically requires specialized materials that are designed to accept and permanently bond with sublimation inks. When it comes to PVC cards, standard PVC is not designed for dye-sublimation and will likely not produce the results you're looking for.  Hope that helps. Although I have used a fargo ribbon printer to print directly onto PVC.